# Leaflet + GeoJson converted from OSM Data - Relations

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap, geojson

I'm trying to display bicycle relations which I downloaded from geofabrik, converted with osmconvert, filtered with osmfilter and converted to geojson. At the moment Leaflet displays line strings and nodes correctly on the map. The problem is with data from relations that are included in the file. Here is a part of my GeoJson file (I won't include whole file because it's just too big):

```
var rower = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "id": "way/27149688",
    "properties": {
      "type": "way",
      "id": "27149688",
      "tags": {
        "agricultural": "no",
        "bicycle": "yes",
        "highway": "residential",
        "maxweightrating:hgv": "24",
        "maxweightrating:hgv:condtitional": "none @ marked",
        "name": "Mikołaja Reja",
        "source:maxweightrating:hgv": "PL:sign_B-5-note"
      },
      "relations": [{
        "role": "",
        "rel": "4046118",
        "reltags": {
          "colour": "blue",
          "description": "Leśna trasa rowerowa, preferowany rower górski / Forest track, Mountain Bike preferred",
          "lcn_ref": "niebieski",
          "name": "Szlak Trójmiejski",
          "network": "rcn",
          "route": "bicycle",
          "type": "route"
        }
      }],
      "meta": {
        "timestamp": "2014-04-17T11:58:45Z",
        "version": "20",
        "changeset": "21747999",
        "user": "wojtas82",
        "uid": "729745"
      },
      "tainted": true
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "LineString",
      "coordinates": [[
          18.5024141,
          54.4354139
      ],[
          18.503622,
          54.4353485
      ],[
          18.5053714,
          54.4352858
      ]]
    }
  }]
};
```

As you can see relations are in square brackets. I wish to display different colours of tracks depending on relations>reltags>colour tag. Here is my main html file (actually the party that doesn't work):

```
var rower2 = L.geoJson(rower, {
    style: function (feature) {
        switch (feature.properties.relations) {
            case 'blue':
                return {color: "#ff0000"};
            case 'red':
                return {color: "#0000ff"};
        }
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

I tried to modify this part (feature.properties.relations) to (feature.properties.relations.reltags.colour) but it doesn't work. Is there any way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't working because `feature.properties.relations` is an array (hence the surrounding brackets) containing objects. To access the objects stored in that array you can use array notation like this: `feature.properties.relations[0]` for the first object in the array, `feature.properties.relations[1]` for the second object in the array and so forth. So if you want to access the colour property of the reltags object in the first relation object in the array you should use `feature.properties.relations[0].reltags.colour`

```
var rower2 = L.geoJson(rower, {
    style: function (feature) {
        switch (feature.properties.relations[0].reltags.colour) {
            case 'blue':
                return {color: "#ff0000"};
            case 'red':
                return {color: "#0000ff"};
        }
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

But my guess is that you're gonna be running into trouble because OSM did use an array for relations with a purpose. My guess is that there can be multiple relations for a feature, and thus it could have multiple colors.

Here's a working example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/EjCCsb?p=preview

PS. I'm wondering why you're returning '#FF0000' when the case is `blue`, because that's the code for red, same thing with case `red`, you're returning '#0000FF' which is the code for blue. Other than that the code is working fine when you use `feature.properties.relations[0].reltags.colour` as you can see in the example i supplied.

Comment: Yes, a feature (e.g. a road) can be part of multiple relations (e.g. multiple bicycle routes).

Comment: I've added an example on Plunker to my answer, works perfectly as described in my answer. Also, you're not supposed to post an answer with more info on your question, that's what the edit link under your question is for. So you can edit your question and add more info if needed. You'de best delete that answer because it can confuse other users. (heh i see you did that already)

Comment: Hi, sorry for answer below... I wasn't sure where to post it. I've already tested your version and it works :) The problem is with the whole file but I will investigate it and get back here shortly :) Thank you very much! You are very helpul :) And the colours were random, just for testing purposes, I will edit them as well.

Comment: I have edited Geojson file with Qgis so now I have all attributes in properites and there is no problem with displaying certain attributes. Thanks for the hints! Now the map looks like this : http://members.upcpoczta.pl/w.racek/mapa.html I still need to add some more interactivity (highlight on mouseover and zoom to feature) but so far so good :)

Comment: This is absolutely not the way to ask another question. You've asked a question, got a working answer and accepted it. Now you're not supposed to edit your question to ask another followup question, you need to create a new one. This is very confusing for other users looking for similar solutions and also nobody is going to view this question because it's already got an accepted answer. Just post a new question with the relevant title, content and code so others can help too. I'll be glad to help you then.

Comment: Ok. Will do.sorry again!